# hash doesn't show me a list of Bash commands

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hash

I read in the O'reilly Bash book (third edition, 2005) **what I understood** as that if I'll execute `hash` I'll see a "hash table" with a list of all possible Bash commands plus all commands common to most environments including Bash that are available in my system.

Yet in WSL-Ubuntu (16.04 - xenial) I executed `hash` and got just:

> ```
> hits    command
>    1    /usr/bin/mesg
> ```

Might this be unique to WSL (I don't have a non-WSL Ubuntu machine to test on right now)?

### Update

I misunderstood the chapter - the hash table doesn't include all Bash commands but seemingly **all recently used non-bash commands** (with the path to the files containing their data);

it's just that the authors gave a list containing some **very common** commands which I mistakenly confused as "builtin" from a quick look on the list, although they are standalone utilities (and here's the list from the book - page 72):

```
cat
stat
less
man
apropos
more
ln
ls
ps
vi
```

Of course, these are not Bash builtin commands like `cd`, `echo`, `set`, `shopt`, `source`, `bash`, `if`, `case`, `for`, `while`, `kill`, `trap`, `exit`, etc, but standalone utilities very common in Bash based environments.

By now I've internalized the difference deep enough and humbly believe I won't confuse in this embarrasing way again. This is an important lesson for me; I never really dived deep enough on the differences between what very common program is a Bash builtin or a "very common" utility in Bash-based environments that might be grasped as a "builtin" but my stance is - "no more!".

Comment: By the way, if you at any time wonder about a particular command being a `bash` keyword, a builtin, an external program or whatnot, just run `type -a COMMAND`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `help hash` shows, the `hash` function is used to determine and remember the full pathnames of programs:

```
hash: hash [-lr] [-p pathname] [-dt] [name ...]
    Remember or display program locations.

    Determine and remember the full pathname of each command NAME.  If
    no arguments are given, information about remembered commands is displayed.

    Options:
      -d        forget the remembered location of each NAME
      -l        display in a format that may be reused as input
      -p pathname       use PATHNAME as the full pathname of NAME
      -r        forget all remembered locations
      -t        print the remembered location of each NAME, preceding
                each location with the corresponding NAME if multiple
                NAMEs are given
    Arguments:
      NAME      Each NAME is searched for in $PATH and added to the list
                of remembered commands.

    Exit Status:
    Returns success unless NAME is not found or an invalid option is given.
```

In your case it returns `/usr/bin/mesg` because obviously `mesg` has been called before and `hash` now remembers its path.

To get help on `bash` builtins, functions etc. there’s the `help` function. Call it without an argument to get a list of shell commands defined internally. To get a list of `bash` builtins you can use `compgen -b`.